# Kubernetes KOPS cluster creation issue - error reading cluster configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes, kops

I can't create a kubernetes cluster when using KOPS, the error message I get is:

`error reading cluster configuration "fraxxxx-k8s-devopsxxx": error reading s3://devopsxxx-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com/fraxxx-k8s-devopsbcn/config: Could not retrieve location for AWS bucket devopsxxx-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com`

I did create my s3 bucket, I though it was an issue like the bucket was not created, so I browsed my AWS bucket and it was in there.

Executing the command below always displays an error for me:

```
$ sudo kops create cluster fraxxxx-k8s-devopsxxx --zones eu-west-3a --yes

error reading cluster configuration "fraxxxx-k8s-devopsxxx": error reading s3://devopsxxx-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com/fraxxx-k8s-devopsbcn/config: Could not retrieve location for AWS bucket devopsxxx-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com
```

I did configure my Access Keys:

```
:~$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************IYFQ]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [****************+SXJ]: 
Default region name [eu-west-3]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

Even exported the keys as an env vars:

```
~$ echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXIYFQ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+SXJ
```

The bucket name was exported as env var as well, and I double checked it via GUI and it seems fine.

```
~$ echo $KOPS_STATE_STORE
s3://devxxxxxx-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Executed it again the create command but now adding the "state" flag, and still it is failing.

```
$ sudo kops create cluster fraxxxx-k8s-devxxxxx --zones eu-west-3a --yes --state s3://devxxxxxx-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com

error reading cluster configuration "fraxxxx-k8s-devxxxxxx": error reading s3://devxxxxxx-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com/fraxxxx-k8s-devopsbcn/config: Could not retrieve location for AWS bucket devopsbcn-k8s-learn.s3.amazonaws.com
```

I expect to run the create command and have a working kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Does the user associated with those keys have the `s3:GetBucketLocation` permission per https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/state.md#cross-account-state-store-aws?

Comment: Hi @AndyShinn, Actually you gave me a very good tip, because I was using the AWS root user and it seems that it is not a good practise, and if I'm not mistaken, AWS is now limiting the root user by default, so people needs to create an IAM user and give specific permissions.

I found myself the answer, and it seems that after some newer version of KOPS, you need create the Kubernetes Cluster with flags, I will post my findinds, Thank You :-)

Comment: Hi @farp332, could you post your findings as an answer? community would be grateful,

Comment: @Black_Bacardi Will do, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Answering to myself***
As per AWS official documentation,after KOPS ver 1.6.1 you require:

1) Top level domain to create the kubernetes cluster.

2) IAM User with specific permission, because using the root AWS Secret Keys is complicated, or now limited.

I use these permission for my IAM user:

`AmazonEC2FullAccess
IAMFullAccess
AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess
AmazonVPCFullAccess
AmazonRoute53FullAccess`

3) And of course you should use the Access Key and Secret from your IAM user.

4) Then an AWS route53 hosted zone. Steps in the link below

5) The "create" cluster command that worked for me:
`$ sudo kops create cluster --name cluster.kubernetes-aws.io --zones eu-west-3a --state s3://xxxxx-kops-state-store --master-size=t2.micro --yes`

Mind the flags `--name` and `--state`

Please use this documentation to accomplish the requirements above `https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/kubernetes-clusters-aws-kops/`

Beside those points listed above, I had to figure out few more things, like:

A) Adding my api DNS entry from my AWS route53 to `/etc/hosts`, i.e api.cluster.kubernetes-aws.io 32.56.87.41, Because when I ran this command `kops validate cluster`, it was trying to look locally on my PC for the cluster, see below:

**wrong**

`$ sudo kops validate cluster --name cluster.kubernetes-aws.io --state s3://xxxxx-kops-state-store
Validating cluster cluster.kubernetes-aws.io
unexpected error during validation: unable to resolve Kubernetes cluster API URL dns: lookup api.cluster.xxxxxxxxx.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host`

**right**

```
$ sudo kops validate cluster --name cluster.kubernetes-aws.io --state s3://xxxxx-kops-state-store
[sudo] password for prometheus: 
Validating cluster cluster.kubernetes-aws.io

INSTANCE GROUPS
NAME            ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX SUBNETS
master-eu-west-3a   Master  t2.micro    1   1   eu-west-3a
nodes           Node    t2.medium   2   2   eu-west-3a

NODE STATUS
NAME                        ROLE    READY
ip-172-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-3.xxxxx.internal    master  True

VALIDATION ERRORS
KIND    NAME                            MESSAGE
Machine i-05755f2ba8b9ebea0                 machine "i-05755f2ba8b9ebea0" has not yet joined cluster
Machine i-05d0a12acf5434e26                 machine "i-05d0a12acf5434e26" has not yet joined cluster
Pod kube-system/kube-dns-57dd96bb49-q6zwc           kube-system pod "kube-dns-57dd96bb49-q6zwc" is pending
Pod kube-system/kube-dns-autoscaler-867b9fd49d-hgpf8    kube-system pod "kube-dns-autoscaler-867b9fd49d-hgpf8" is pending
```

B) Again mind the flags `--name` and `--state` when trying to validate the cluster, otherwise you get errors.

C) Important, when creating the cluster, you have to add the machine type otherwise you get the error below.

`error assigning default machine type for masters: error finding default machine type: could not find a suitable supported instance type for the instance group "master-eu-west-3a" (type "Master") in region "eu-west-3"`

D) My s3 bucket was not being picked from the env vars (or something like that), and I just passed it as flag with `--state`. For point C and D I created the cluster succesfully as follows:

`$ sudo kops create cluster --name cluster.kubernetes-aws.io --zones eu-west-3a --state s3://xxxxx-kops-state-store --master-size=t2.micro --yes`

Comment: Hi, can you please help me this error. thank you. `error reading cluster configuration "srikanth.k8s.local": error reading s3://srikanth-kops-state-store/srikanth.k8s.local/config: Unable to list AWS regions: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: i/o timeout`